# How to validate a field depending on the value of another field in Enaml?

Tags: enaml

Let's say I have a form with 2 IntFields.  How can I validate IntField B depending on the input in IntField A?
e.g. if A == 1, B can only be within 0-30; if A == 2, B can only be within 0-50; else B can be any other numbers

From all I can google, I can only find IntValidator which validates the field only without the ability to link to another field.  No examples that I can find that shows how I can update the min/max values in the IntValidator, nor any custom Validator which can take the value of another field such that validation can change according to change of value in another field...

```
enamldef IntFieldsWindow( Window ):

    Container:
        Form:
            padding=0
            Label:
                text = 'Field A'
            IntField: fld_a:
                value = 0
            Label:
                text = 'Field B'
            IntField: fld_b:
                value = 0
```

After some tests, it is actually possible to pass fld_a to a custom validator, then get the fld_a.value in the validate function, finally set the custom validator to fld_b.  Not sure if it is the way to do such validation though.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to break the data out into a model and have it validate the members using an observer that is called when either member changes.

Then make the `IntField` bind to the model value (using `<<`) and update the model value using a notification handler (`::`) that catches and reports validation errors.

For example:

```
from atom.api import Atom, Int, observe
from enaml.stdlib.fields import IntField
from enaml.widgets.api import Window, Container, Label, Form


class Model(Atom):
    a = Int()
    b = Int()

    @observe('a', 'b')
    def _validate(self, change):
        # When a or b is changed validate the model state
        a, b = self.a, self.b
        if a == 1:
            if b < 0 or b > 30:
                raise ValueError("B is out of range")
        elif a == 2:
            if b < 0 or b > 50:
                raise ValueError("B is out of range")


enamldef Main(Window):
    attr model = Model()
    Container:
        Form:
            padding=0
            Label:
                text = 'Field A'
            IntField: fld_a:
                value << model.a
                value ::
                    error.text = ''
                    try:
                        model.a = change['value']
                    except ValueError as e:
                        error.text = str(e)
            Label:
                text = 'Field B'
            IntField: fld_b:
                value << model.b
                value ::
                    error.text = ''
                    try:
                        model.b = change['value']
                    except ValueError as e:
                        error.text = str(e)
        Label: 
            text << 'A:{} B:{}'.format(model.a, model.b)
        Label: error:
            pass
```

Notice the that the label outputting the model values never has an invalid state!  The validator on the model will ensure this never happens.